# How to scroll a portion of my window using protractor-jasmine

Tags: javascript, scroll, protractor

I want to test by clicking an element which is only visible when the sidebar section is scrolled. The sidebar is in the left end of the website and the element is in the bottom portion of the sidebar. I used:

```
browser.executeScript('window.sidebar.scrollTo(0,0);').then(function ()
```

but it's not working.

```
<div class="sidebar" data-active-color="white" data-background-color="red" data-image="../assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg">
        <sidebar-cmp>

        <div class="logo">
            <div class="logo-normal">
                <a class="simple-text" href="https://www.creative-tim.com">
                    Creative Tim
                </a>
            </div>

            <div class="logo-img">
                <img src="/assets/img/angular2-logo-white.png">
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="sidebar-wrapper">

            <div class="user">
                <div class="photo">
                    <img src="../assets/img/faces/avatar.jpg">
                </div>
                <div class="info">
                    <a class="collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample">
                        <span>
                            Tania Andrew
                            <b class="caret"></b>
                        </span>
                    </a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
                        <ul class="nav">
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <span class="sidebar-mini">MP</span>
                                    <span class="sidebar-normal">My Profile</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <span class="sidebar-mini">EP</span>
                                    <span class="sidebar-normal">Edit Profile</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="javascript:void(0)">
                                    <span class="sidebar-mini">S</span>
                                    <span class="sidebar-normal">Settings</span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="nav-container">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li routerlinkactive="active" class="active visible">
                        <a href="#/dashboard">
                            <i class="material-icons">dashboard</i>
                            <p>Dashboard</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#componentsExamples">
                            <i class="material-icons">apps</i>
                            <p>Components
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="componentsExamples">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/buttons">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">B</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Buttons</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/grid">

                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">GS</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Grid System</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/panels">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">P</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Panels</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/sweet-alert">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">SA</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Sweet Alert</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/notifications">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">N</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Notifications</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/icons">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">I</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Icons</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/components/typography">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">T</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Typography</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#formsExamples">
                            <i class="material-icons">content_paste</i>
                            <p>Forms
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="formsExamples">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/forms/regular">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">RF</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Regular Forms</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/forms/extended">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">EF</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Extended Forms</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/forms/validation">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">VF</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Validation Forms</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/forms/wizard">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">W</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Wizard</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#tablesExamples">
                            <i class="material-icons">grid_on</i>
                            <p>Tables
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="tablesExamples">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/tables/regular">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">RT</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Regular Tables</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/tables/extended">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">ET</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Extended Tables</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/tables/datatables.net">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">DT</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">DataTables.net</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#mapsExamples">
                            <i class="material-icons">place</i>
                            <p>Maps
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="mapsExamples">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/maps/google">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">GM</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Google Maps</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/maps/fullscreen">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">FSM</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Full Screen Map</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/maps/vector">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">VM</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Vector Map</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a href="#/widgets">
                            <i class="material-icons">widgets</i>

                            <p>Widgets</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a href="#/charts">
                            <i class="material-icons">timeline</i>

                            <p>Charts</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a href="#/calendar">
                            <i class="material-icons">date_range</i>

                            <p>Calendar</p>
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li routerlinkactive="active">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#pagesExamples">
                            <i class="material-icons">image</i>
                            <p>Pages
                                <b class="caret"></b>
                            </p>
                        </a>
                        <div class="collapse" id="pagesExamples">
                            <ul class="nav">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./pricing.html">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">P</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Pricing</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/pages/timeline">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">T</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Timeline Page</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./login.html">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">LP</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Login Page</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./register.html">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">RP</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Register Page</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="./lock.html">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">LSP</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">Lock Screen Page</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li routerlinkactive="active">
                                    <a href="#/pages/user">
                                        <span class="sidebar-mini">UP</span>
                                        <span class="sidebar-normal">User Page</span>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </li>

                </ul>
            <div class="sidebar-moving-tab" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 5px, 0px);"></div></div>

        </div>
</sidebar-cmp>
        <div class="sidebar-background" style="background-image: url(assets/img/sidebar-1.jpg)"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var filter = theSwitch.pageBar;
            var scrollIntoView = function () {
              arguments[0].scrollIntoView();
            };
          browser.executeScript(scrollIntoView, filter);
          theSwitch.pageBar.click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Specify the position at what location you have to scroll, ***try this one***.

```
browser.executeScript('window.scrollTo(0,1000);').then(function () {
    browser.sleep(5000);
    console.log('Window ScrollTo','Done');
}).then(function() {
    //wait for element to be displayed 
     browser.driver.wait(function(){
        return someElement.isDisplayed().then(function (isVisible){
            return isVisible === true;
            },50000, 'Element not present ' );
     },50000)
});
```

Comment: I want to scroll the sidebar only and not the whole window of the website. How to scroll an iframe or some sidebar inside a website, without scrolling the whole website? @Surendra Jnawali

Comment: It is pretty similar concept. Can you please post your side bar code also.

Comment: Hi, I have added it in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using this line for scrolling.
You can also try it on console before using it on protractor.
e.g. `$(".sidebar").scrollLeft(1000)`

```
strPixels = 1000 //value in pixel
strClass = '.sidebar' //class of the element with scrollbar

browser.executeScript('$("' + strClass + '").scrollLeft(' + strPixels + ')');
```

Note: you can use `scrollLeft` or `scrollTop` to scroll horizontally or vertically.